# Google Sheets Search for entries and give result

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

i've the following problem.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NThvIXO27UM2XLNWAVgg14lvn_iLqkaNSj0ZIa8vZ-A/edit?usp=sharing

I think this is more than enough explained what I need and trying to figure out how this can be done.
I know google sheets good, but now im stuck over here about 2 hours. I googled but didn't found the right solution for me.

If anyone could help would be amazing. This document can be edited from anyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A23&D2:D23; {H28:H&D28:D\E28:E}; 2; 0)))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: This turned up in low quality post probably because of the Plate column. I've not recommended deletion because this table was given by the OP, so it's not the fault of this answerer.

Comment: I just checked your profile... is *this* a result of *that*?

Comment: Add an explanation of what was wrong with the OP's code, what you changed, and why you changed it. That would change this answer from a "give someone a fish" to "teach someone to fish."